# Can't connect two laptops using LAN cable

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wiring, cat5, crossover-cable

I followed the tutorial at http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-25120-how-to-connect-two-laptops-using-lan-cable for connecting my two desktop computers with a LAN wire.

The computers run the same Operating Systems (Windows XP), and I turned the firewall off on both systems, but I still can't connect.

Can someone please help?

Comment: yes i have a cross-over cable

Comment: laptops or desktops? and are you trying to connect them to share internet or for other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you followed the steps in that links (i.e. you set a static IP address on both computers and used a crossover cable), then you may also want to try setting the Ethernet speed rather than letting it Auto-negotiate (or Auto detect) - I've found that PCs often do not like this configuration in a Crossover (PC-to-PC) configuration.

To do this, go into the properties of you network adapter (Control Panel, Network Connections, right-click the LAN Adapter and choose Properties). Click configure (next to the LAN adapter name). If you have the Intel ProSet software loaded, then there will be a tab called Link Speed - if you don't have ProSet, look for a property called Speed and Duplex (or similar).

Now set Speed and Duplex to something other than Auto Detect or Auto Negotiate (e.g. set it to 100Mbps/Full Duplex) - make sure you have the same setting on both Computers (and that both Computers are capable of the speed/duplex you are setting).

Comment: This is good advice, duplexing issues can cause a lot of connection problems from lack thereof to major speed decreases. I would however double-check that the cable is indeed crossover and not straight through. "LAN wire" does not instill much confidence in me that it is certainly a crossover.

Comment: @MaQleod - Good point about the words "LAN wire" (+1). If he has the correct cable (and now you have put doubt in my mind), then it is more likely Speed/Duplex issues from what I've experienced before (unless he's doing something else fundamentally wrong).

Answer (score 0):

If its to share internet, you probably can use Internet connection sharing for that -

Internet -ethernet-> system running ICS -ethernet-> second system

I'm not sure if you can run ICS without an internet connection, but it'll take care of most of the setup involved. Just run the wizard, and set 'i want to share my internet connection' on one system, and set the other one up as the client.